# Select from ComboBox an item (name) and auto-insert the right foreign key

Tags: java, mysql, sql, applet, jcombobox

So basically what I want to do is:

1. Select from a ComboBox a professor name for example:

"Dan Munteanu"

I did this by doing this

```
try{
                String sql="select * from profesori";
                PreparedStatement pst=connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();

                while(rs.next()){
                    int idprof=rs.getInt("idProfesor");
                    String nume=rs.getString("Nume");
                    String prenume=rs.getString("Prenume");
                    comboBoxProfesor.addItem(nume+" "+prenume);
                }

            }catch(Exception e1){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1);
            }
```

2. When I execute the query in my Java Application [as you've seen my previous query should have all the values from my profesori table which are: (idprofesor,name,surname,idmaterie)] I want it to automatically add it's IDPROFESOR (unique key) to my Students table (by being a foreign key).

[this is my database diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vYEo.png) ||
[this is my applet add panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNMvk.png)

So far I am trying out this query:

```
try {
                String sql="insert into Elevi (NumeElev,InitialaTata,PrenumeElev,ScoalaDeProvenienta,Clasa,Nota,IdProfesor,IdMaterie) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                PreparedStatement pst=connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                pst.setString(1, textNumeElev.getText());
                pst.setString(2, textInitialaTata.getText());
                pst.setString(3, textPrenumeElev.getText());
                pst.setString(4, textScoala.getText());
                pst.setString(5, textClasa.getText());
                pst.setString(6, textNota.getText());
                pst.setString(7, comboBoxProfesor.getSelectedItem().toString());
                pst.setString(8, comboBoxMaterie.getSelectedItem().toString());

                pst.execute();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Saved");

                pst.close();

            } catch (Exception e3){
                e3.printStackTrace();
            }
```

and of course it won't work because my 7 and 8 values should be INT type but I get them as strings... Basically I want to save my PK when I am doing the query to populate the ComboBox (somewhere in the background) and add it only when I am executing the last query in the main table as FK. I know that if I will only get my combo boxes to return only the INT values of my professors tables I will be able to do this but I want it to be easily used by someone who does not know what those ID numbers mean.

Sorry if I am troubling you guys, I hope you can get my question :)

Comment: Possibly use `comboBox.getSelectedIndex()` instead of `comboBox.getSelectedItem()` ?

Comment: I managed to do it by adding getSelectedIndex()+1 as my ID's were starting from 1. Thanks a milion times!

Comment: Is the selected index in the combo box (a number from [0..item count - 1]) equal to the database ID (a foreign key)?

Comment: Yes. It's a FK for my main table "Elevi" (students). Now the problem I am facing it's related to the professor teaching class (math,english). For example: professor 1 is teaching class 3 (math) and he shouldn't be able to be inserted in the database as teaching class 1 (english) but as for now, he is :\

Comment: You could fill the classes combo box whenever a professor is selected from the professor combo box (assuming you have the list of classes each professor is teaching).

Comment: The classes are a completely different table in my database screenshot they represent "materie" and the foreign key in professors table is "idMaterie". I can't auto fill once a professor is selected since these students have a grade on each class they attempted. @FreekdeBruijn

Comment: So each professor is teaching one class (because there is one `IdMaterie` column in your professor table)? In that case, selecting a professor will select the class as well? I don't understand what you mean by "since these students have a grade on each class they attempted".

Comment: Ok I am bad at explaining things. So, each professor teaches a class (only-one). The students are taking exams to different classes. All I have to do is to insert them in a database. As of now I am able to add student "x" having profesor 1 that teaches class 3 (which is his "idmaterie") but if I try to add anyway profesor 1 that teaches class 1 (not his idmaterie) I am still able to save it to the DB. It's a conflict here since I need to manually select the class they attended too. I hope I made myself clear this time :(

Comment: In that case I would use one combo box that contains the name of the professor and the class (for example: "Dan Munteanu: Mathematics"). You could take another look at my answer below - it's not that complicated. If you add the class name and class ID to the `Professor` class, you can adjust the constructor, add some getters, and change the `toString` method to get it to work.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will give it a try tomorrow morning!

Answer (score 0):

You can put all sorts of objects in a `JComboBox`. The combo box uses the `toString` method to determine how to show an item. You can put additional information such as the `id` in a custom class, like the `Professor` class in the example below.

**Edit: added the class name and id to the `Professor` class**

As discussed in the comments to the question above, you can also add the class name and class id to the `Professor` class. This way both the professor id and the class id are available when you pick a professor from the combo box (that combo box can show both the name of the professor and the class name):

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class ObjectComboBox {
    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new ObjectComboBox().createAndShowGui());
    }

    private void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Stack Overflow");
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JComboBox<Professor> comboBox = new JComboBox<>(new Professor[]{
                new Professor("Dan Munteanu", 123456, "Mathematics", 3),
                new Professor("Daniel Roy Connelly", 424242, "English", 1)
        });
        panel.add(comboBox);

        comboBox.addActionListener(
                actionEvent -> {
                    Professor professor = (Professor) comboBox.getSelectedItem();
                    System.out.println("Professor id: " + professor.getId());
                    System.out.println("Class id: " + professor.getClassId());
                }
        );

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}


class Professor {
    private final String name;
    private final int id;
    private final String className;
    private final int classId;

    Professor(String name, int id, String className, int classId) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.className = className;
        this.classId = classId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getClassName() {
        return className;
    }

    public int getClassId() {
        return classId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + ": " + className;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I am not an advanced guy in Java, this is just for a project for college. The getSelectedIndex() method worked.

Comment: Great! Keep your project as simple as possible.